# Rails: unable to deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

***UPDATE***: Even though I'm completely removing `sqlite3`gem from my `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, it is still being installed on heroku.

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to Heroku, and even tho I followed the instructions, I get the infamous sqlite3 error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_dfa00c2b50bad4da069069454f39d2b2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160925-219-11i619z.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_dfa00c2b50bad4da069069454f39d2b2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_dfa00c2b50bad4da069069454f39d2b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_dfa00c2b50bad4da069069454f39d2b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing less 2.6.0
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

The problem is that I have exactly the same `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` that I had with a similar project, and this was successfully deployed to Heroku.

Here's my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'shotgun', '~> 0.9.2'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
```

And my `Gemfile.lock`, which indeed contains the `sqlite3` gem:

```
GIT
remote: git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git
  revision: d3776ddd0b89d28fdebfd6e1c1541348cc90e5cc
  specs:
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs (>= 2.2.2, >= 2.2)
      less-rails (>= 2.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      nio4r (~> 1.2)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
    activerecord (5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (7.1.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (4.2.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    font-awesome-rails (4.6.3.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    geocoder (1.4.0)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    gravatarify (3.0.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.2.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.7.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (> 2, < 4)
      tilt
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.19.0)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    puma (3.6.0)
    rack (2.0.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.0.1)
      actioncable (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activerecord (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    simple_form (3.3.1)
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.1)
      activemodel (> 4, < 5.1)
    spring (1.7.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (~> 1.2)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.3.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      debug_inspector
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise
  font-awesome-rails
  geocoder
  gravatarify (~> 3.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  pg
  puma (~> 3.0)
  rails (~> 5.0.0, >= 5.0.0.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  twitter-bootstrap-rails!
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe you should use sqlite on heroku? this error just proves =)

Comment: @Aleksey Heroku doesn't support `sqlite3`, hence the use of the `pg`gem

Comment: I thought about that. thank you but I never use sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was trying to push to heroku without having committed my changes. Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 1):

sqlite 3 gem cannot be installed in heroku. It is a sample database which comes default with Rails. In case of production, you will have to use some advanced database. Please check this link for more info https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: I have already read it, and the part I can't figure out is `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#getting-a-sqlite-error-even-though-it-is-not-in-the-gemfile`

Comment: Can you please bundle install your gems locally and then push along with your gemfile.lock to heroku?

Comment: I did so, but it is the same result

Answer (score 0):

Heroku provides Postgresql databases as services for your apps. Read [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), why it is not a good idea to use sqlite3 in production mode.

So you need to change your `Gemfile` to something like this:

```
group :production do
  # postgresql
  gem 'pg'
  # enabling features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  # SQLite3 Database
  gem 'sqlite3'
  ...
end
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and if you see the `Gemfile` I have, I have the `pg`gem in the production environment, while the `sqlite3`gem is in the development